# SwiftUI ForEach-Loops getting errors

Tags: swift, for-loop, swiftui

I'm trying to build a ForEach()-Loop in SwiftUI for building UI-Elements, but I'm getting this error-message:

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

Here is my code:

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    ForEach((1...10).reversed(), id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
```

The Error is pointing on the Line with the ForEach-Statement. I tried to follow the tutorial by Paul Hudson, see: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: remove `Spacer()` from `ForEach`.
`ForEach` expects to return **one** value of type `some View`.
You could wrap your `Text()` and `Spacer()` into `HStack` or `VStack`, but in this case you couldn't access the each number in your array via closure syntax (`$0` notation should be changed to `{ element in }` ).
So the next code would work:

```swift
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach((1...10).reversed(), id: \.self) { number in
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(number)")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you. I'm just kicking into SwiftUI and some errors are weird.